# Run a Vim command _after_ loading vimrc, but _before_ opening the file?

Tags: vimrc, swap-file

Is there a way to tell Vim from command line to run a specific command *after* running the vimrc, but *before* loading a file?

E. g.

- `vim --cmd <cmd> <file>` runs `<cmd>` before loading vimrc,
- `vim -c <cmd> <file>` runs `<cmd>` after loading vimrc *and* after opening the file.

Is there a middle-ground?

---

In case of an XY problem, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm trying to use Vim to open and edit a huge file (~50GB). I have enough RAM to load the file, but not enough disk space and bandwidth for any sort of extra temporary files. My vimrc enables backups, swap files and undo files by default, and I'd like to find a way to disable all three for a specific Vim invocation. This needs to be done before the file is opened (otherwise a swap file will be created), but after vimrc is loaded (otherwise vimrc is going to override the settings).

Comment: Could you differentiate by file type? You can disable swapping, backups, etc. in this case.

Comment: Check the [LargeFile plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/LargeFile) I think it uses a `BufReadPre` auto-command

Comment: Possibly combine the cmd flag with VimEnter autocommand? Can’t recall exactly when that runs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a low-tech approach.

In your `vimrc`, put all the relevant options behind a guard. Something like:

```
if !exists('$LARGE_FILE')
    set backup
    " etc.
endif
```

If the environment variable exists (its value doesn't matter) don't set those options.

If the environment variable doesn't exist, set those options.

Now, in your shell, you can call Vim like this:

```
$ LARGE_FILE=1 vim 50gbfile.json
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did :) I just wanted to know if there's a better way.

Comment: Define "better". If you want an automagic solution, the plugin mentioned in the comments is certainly "better". IMO, the problem and the solution are too trivial to require a third-party plugin.